# Statistics Probability Event Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose A and B are two independent events, associated with a random experiment. The probability of occurrence of event A or B is 0.8, while the probability of occurrence of event A is 0.5.Determine the occurrence of the probability of Event B.

I have searched a lot for this question. I am new to probability. How can we convert the basic formulae for this?

P(A)+P(B)-P(A intersection B)= P(A union B)

Thanks for the help in advance. Please down mark this question as after this my account will get blocked

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  You want $P(B)$...you have an equation in which that term appears...which values in that equation do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$A$ and $B$ are independent, hence $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Are you able to solve the problem now?

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Because $A$ and $B$ are independent, we may say that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

$P(A)=0.5$ and $P(A\cup B)=0.8$. Let $P(B)$ denoted by $x$. We have the following equation for $x$:

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(A)+P(A\cap B)$

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(A)+P(A)P(B)$

$0.8=0.5+x-0.5x.$$

That is $$0.3=0.5x.$$

From here $$x=\frac35.$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me out